# Unity WebGL - Locating code that triggers Reflection.emit

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I've run into the dreaded Reflection.emit issue in my webplayer build and am unable to locate what is triggering it. I'm currently commenting out code method by method and rebuilding to locate the cause and have narrowed it down to the below.

I'm not using JSON so the various JSON libraries aren't the cause, nor any of the other result suggestions returned by google.

How can i more easily go about locating the cause of this error. I have full stack trace on and well as full debugging, but all i get is the following console output.

> NotSupportedException: C:\Program Files\Unity 2018.2.0b2\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\icalls\mscorlib\System.Reflection.Emit\AssemblyBuilder.cpp(20) : Unsupported internal call for IL2CPP:AssemblyBuilder::basic_init - System.Reflection.Emit is not supported.
>
> Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.AnonHostModuleHolder' threw an exception.

```
//NOTE: appM.procM is a C# .Net 4.x dynamic variable EG: 
//public dynamic procM = GetProcClass(strProcName)

public void ShowProcList() {
    /* Rest of method commented out*/
    if(appM.procM == null){
        procList.Initialize(appM.procM.lstNames, this);
   }
    /* Rest of method commented out*/
}

public void Initialize(List<string> lstNames, UIM um, string currProc=null) {
    uiM = um;

    //cleanup of the list before populating
    foreach(Transform fld in Panel.transform) {
        Destroy(fld.gameObject);
    }
/* Rest of method commented out*/
}
```

**Update:** I narrowed down the problem line of code, but haven't closed the question as there's got to be an easier way than commenting out line by line and rebuilding.

For future searchers, the issue is the **if(appM.procM == null)** check. As procM is a dynamic variable reflection is used which kills AOT in webGL builds. No compiler warnings were generated to save myself from myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i am an idiot, The option Enable Exceptions under Player Settings was set to **Full Without Stacktrace** and not **Full with Stacktrace**.

The value **Full With Stacktrace** contains the pertinent data. Easily locatable in the browsers console. Warning that full debugging does increase build times and slow down the application.